# Find word inside special characters or spaces in multiple files

Tags: text-processing

How to find all matches of exact word in files inside directory (including subdirectories) which may be surrounded by special characters or spaces or nothing (beginning or end of line). I think this is common when searching in source code.

Let's say inside the multiple files I want to find word `is`. It should find these occurences:

`is` (this is the only word in a line)

`(is)`

`"is"`

`this is something`

For example `grep -r in` does find matches inside other words which I don't need.

Comment: but not Frisbee?

Comment: @JacobVlijm exactly.

Comment: `grep -rw` (word match)?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I just want it done using terminal in Ubuntu, just like I would use "grep -r something".

Comment: @steeldriver yes this indeed works! I knew it has to be simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-w` or `--word-regexp` flag e.g.

```
grep -wr 'is' .
```

From `man grep`

```
-w, --word-regexp
       Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
       words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
       at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
       constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
       of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
       Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
       underscore.
```